# Search for bash for loop syntax using perl command

Tags: perl, bash, syntax

I have several bash scripts that need to be modified and I would very much prefer to not do it by hand...  basically, they all contain the line

```
for ((i=${BEGIN} ; i < ${END} ; i++))
```

and I need to change this to

```
for ((i=${BEGIN}-1 ; i < ${END} ; i++))
```

the i=${BEGIN} is unique and appears only once in each file, so I figured I could search and replace it using a simple perl command.  What I came up with is

```
>  perl -w -i -p -e "s/i=\$\{BEGIN\}/i=\$\{BEGIN\}-1/" Script.sh
```

which results in the following error

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "{BEGIN"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "}continue"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What is the syntax error here?

Thanks!

Tsadkiel

Answer (score 7):

Use apostrophes instead of double quotes:

```
perl -w -i -p -e 's/i=\$\{BEGIN\}/i=\$\{BEGIN\}-1/'
```

This way, backslashes aren't removed by shell, so perl sees them and they escape what they should escape.

Answer (score 3):

The bash shell is performing interpolation on the argument `"s/i=\$\{BEGIN\}/i=\$\{BEGIN\}-1/"` before it gets to Perl. Let's see how that might work:

```
$ echo "s/i=\$\{BEGIN\}/i=\$\{BEGIN\}-1/"
s/i=$\{BEGIN\}/i=$\{BEGIN\}-1/
```

The substitution `s/i=$\{BEGIN\}/i=$\{BEGIN\}-1/` is going to be a problem in Perl because Perl will treat the sequence `$\{` as the start of a lookup on the hash variable `%\`, but it will fail to compile because it won't find an (unescaped) closing brace. So what you really want Perl to see is something like

```
s/i=\$\{BEGIN\}/i=\$\{BEGIN\}-1/
```

And there are at least two ways to change your original command-line to accomplish this:

1. Escape the dollar signs:

   `perl -wpi -e "s/i=\\\$\{BEGIN\}/i=\\\$\{BEGIN\}-1/"`
2. Prefer single quotes, which aren't interpolated in bash:

   `perl -wpi -e 's/i=\$\{BEGIN\}/i=\$\{BEGIN\}-1/'`